# Changing the URI default handle.net domain on existing and new items

Tags: java, dspace

I'd like to be able to change the permanent URLs of articles so that we don't have to rely on the Handle.net service.

So far I've found the following online, and upon making the changes in `dspace.cfg` file found that the existing items didn't change.

[How change uri handle from http://hdl.handle.net/ to http://myip in all items](http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/How-change-uri-handle-from-http-hdl-handle-net-to-http-myip-in-all-items-td3285730.html) (Nabble)

I have two questions:

1. How would you go about and change all those default handle.net domains?
2. Why is the default URL using this domain? Is this a good alternative?

Answer (score 1):

1. How would you go about and change all those default handle.net domains ?

   You can update this manually by using SQL query. You should get `handle` field under 'items' table.
2. Why is the default URL using this domain? Is this a good alternative?

   Quoting from [Handle System](http://www.handle.net/)

> The Handle System provides efficient, extensible, and secure
> resolution services for unique and persistent identifiers of digital
> objects, and is a component of CNRI's

When your repository is live and you have subscribed to Handles. You will get unique indentifiers for your digital objects and can be accessed/identified uniquely
. So, even if you change information or change location. Your digital object can be identified without changing its identifier.

This has also use when  you are allowing harvesting data or harvested data from other repositories.